# How to remove random numbers and letters from Drupal css/js file

Tags: caching, drupal

In Drupal 7 performance caching and bandwidth optimization are disabled. Whenever css/js file is loaded, there is a random(?) numbers and letters are attached like http://xxx/modules/system/system.theme.css?o9pvtm , http://xxx/sites/all/themes/test/js/handlebars.runtime.min.js?o9pvtm

How can I remove those "?o9pvtm" so js/css files can be cached by Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These random strings are added to ensure proper caching in browser and reverse proxies/CDN. Whenever the cache is cleared at the drupal end, the random string is changed. This will ensure that the updated files are fetched by the caching system. Generally the caching system can be configured to cache based on complete URL (including the query string). I am not sure about Nginx, but there should be some options to do so.

Comment: Aha okay. I have a Nginx at the front and Varnish at the middle. So css/js files are cached on Varnish instead and I want Nginx to cache them. If I enabled bandwidth aggregation for js/css files on Drupal the Nginx caches them correctly cause those random strings are moved before css/js extension. Anyway I'd like Nginx to cache them without enabling bandwidth aggregation setting on Drupal. Does anyone know how to do it on Nginx?